# Set Viewport to Fixed Size with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, viewport

I want to set my viewport to a specific height using JavaScript. So, for example, I could theoretically set an element to `position: fixed; top: 0;`, but NOT have that element hit the top of the window -- only the top of the newly modified viewport. I've read a couple of tips on how to do this, but I'm seeing any success personally. I'm trying something like this:

```
 document.getElementById('myViewportMetaTag')
 .setAttribute('content', 'width=200');
```

After doing this, the viewport never changes. Specifically, I need to do this in Chrome. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Why would you change the 'viewport' instead of an element on the webpage? You can also set an element to transform: translate(); and create a new scope for 'fixed' positioning.

Comment: How about you show some code in an example?

Comment: I can't manipulate an element because I don't know what that element will be. This will be part of a Chrome extension and will wrap every site a user visits. I will inject a fixed, top: 0 element on the page, and I want to ensure that my element is always on top. The problem is that some sites (like Facebook), have a fixed, top: 0 element that I'd be competing with. I want to manipulate the viewport so that my element is visible regardless by setting it off the viewport but still in view. Hopefully that makes sense...

Comment: The viewport tag is only parsed and used on mobile which doesn't support extensions so your approach wont work. If I understand your problem correctly, I don't think the viewport tag helps with what you want. What you'd really want is to load the page into an iframe and shift it down by the size of your bar but lots of pages are likely to prevent loading into an iframe using X-Frame-Options so I don't have a great solution.

Comment: Good points -- thanks for the feedback, @DavidBokan.